# Flutter Riverpod StateNotifierProvider Async value still loading

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I'm new to Flutter. I use the Riverpod state management library. I am calling a remote API to get a list of board games. If I don't pass a parameter to my query, it returns me a list of popular games, and if I pass a games name parameter, it returns me a list of games containing the parameter in its name.
So I want to display a list of popular games when the user lands on the page, and update the list if the user searches for a game by writing its name in the search bar. Problem: My StateNotifier is not working and stays in loading state. Any help will be appreciated, I'm really lost.

Here is my `remote_api.dart`:

```
final boardGamesListProvider = FutureProvider.family.autoDispose<List<BoardGame>, String>((ref, request) => RemoteApi().getBoardGames(request));

class RemoteApi {

  Future<List<BoardGame>> getBoardGames(String request) async {
    // Appel WS
    try {
      final response = await Dio().get('https://api.boardgameatlas.com/api/search?name=$request&client_id=JLBr5npPhV');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(response.data);
        final results = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(data['games']);
        if (results.isNotEmpty) {
          return results.map((e) => BoardGame.fromMap(e)).toList();
        }
      }
      return [];
    } on DioError catch (err) {
      print(err);
      throw ErrorHandler(message: err.response?.statusMessage ?? 'Something went wrong!');
    } on SocketException catch (err) {
      print(err);
      throw const ErrorHandler(message: 'Please check your connection.');
    }
  }
}
```

My `search_game_controller.dart`:

```
final boardGamesListControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<BoardGameList, AsyncValue<List<BoardGame>>>((ref) {
  return BoardGameList(const AsyncValue.data([]), ref);
});

class BoardGameList extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<List<BoardGame>>> {
  BoardGameList(AsyncValue<List<BoardGame>> items, this.ref) : super(items);

  final Ref ref;

  Future<void> search(String request) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    ref.read(boardGamesListProvider(request)).when(data: (data) {
      AsyncValue.data(data);
    }, error: (err, stackTrace) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(err, stackTrace: stackTrace);
    }, loading: () {
      state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    });
  }
}
```

My `search_game_screen.dart`:

```
class SearchGameScreen extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const SearchGameScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final searchController = TextEditingController();
    final boardGameListAsync = ref.watch(boardGamesListControllerProvider);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: searchController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Search a game',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Search',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    ref
                    .read(boardGamesListControllerProvider.notifier).search(searchController.text);
                    print(boardGameListAsync);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: boardGameListAsync
                .when(
                  data: (boardGamesList) {
                    return BoardGamesList(boardGames: boardGamesList);
                  },
                  loading: () =>
                      const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                  error: (error, _) => ErrorScreen(message: error.toString()),
                ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BoardGamesList extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const BoardGamesList({Key? key, required this.boardGames}) : super(key: key);
  final List<BoardGame> boardGames;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: boardGames.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final boardGame = boardGames[index];
        return BoardGameItemWidget(boardGame: boardGame);
      },
    );
  }
}

class BoardGameItemWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  const BoardGameItemWidget({Key? key, required this.boardGame})
      : super(key: key);
  final BoardGame boardGame;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        context.go('/game/details/${boardGame.idFromApi}');
      },
      child: Card(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        elevation: 8,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Hero(
              tag: boardGame.title,
              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                imageUrl: boardGame.image,
                placeholder: (context, url) =>
                    const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
                width: 100,
                height: 100,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
                      child: Text(boardGame.title,
                          style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20))),
                ],
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: Are you having this issue when clicking the "Search" button?

Comment: Yes, at initializing I have no list and no loading state, just nothing on the screen except the search bar. From the moment that I launch a search, the loading state does not stop

Comment: I answered the question.

Comment: Hey @Collembole - Why are you Using AsyncValue<T>? You don't need it, you know that right?

Comment: Hey @DishankJindal, no I don't know that as I explained I'm a Flutter beginner and I'm pretty lost. If you have an alternative solution please share me, it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution :

My screen :

```
class SearchGameScreen extends HookConsumerWidget {
  const SearchGameScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final searchController = TextEditingController();
    AsyncValue<List<BoardGame>> search = ref.watch(boardGamesListControllerProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: searchController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      labelText: 'Search a game',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                height: 50,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 10, 10, 10),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 2),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Search',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                  onPressed: () {
                    ref.read(boardGamesListControllerProvider.notifier).search(searchController.text);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: search.when(
              data: (data) => BoardGamesList(boardGames: data),
              loading: () => const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
              error: (error, _) => const Center(
                child: Text('Uh oh... Something went wrong...',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            )
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My view model :

```
final boardGamesListControllerProvider =
StateNotifierProvider<BoardGameList, AsyncValue<List<BoardGame>>>((ref) {
  return BoardGameList(const AsyncValue.data([]), ref);
});

class BoardGameList extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<List<BoardGame>>> {
  BoardGameList(AsyncValue<List<BoardGame>> items, this.ref) : super(items){
    init();
  }

  final Ref ref;

  Future<void> init() async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    try {
      final search = await ref.watch(boardGamesListProvider('').future);
      state = AsyncValue.data(search);
    } catch (e) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> search(String request) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    try {
      final search = await ref.watch(boardGamesListProvider(request).future);
      state = AsyncValue.data(search);
    } catch (e) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider adding at least two lines describing the solution, a piece of code does not denote what change fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
final boardGamesListControllerProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider<BoardGameList, AsyncValue<List<BoardGame>>>((ref) {
  return BoardGameList(const AsyncValue.data([]), ref);
});

class BoardGameList extends StateNotifier<AsyncValue<List<BoardGame>>> {
  BoardGameList(AsyncValue<List<BoardGame>> items, this.ref) : super(items);

  final Ref ref;

  Future<void> search(String request) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    ref.read(boardGamesListProvider(request)).when(data: (data) {
      state = AsyncValue.data(data);
    }, error: (err, stackTrace) {
      state = AsyncValue.error(err, stackTrace: stackTrace);
    }, loading: () {
      state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Not working, there are no loading state on search, just nothing. Besides, I don't see what you've changed.

Comment: Will it find nothing?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question but I don't see any difference, and my screen is the same. If it's the first initializing, nothing happend, even with a search. But If I switch screen, for example to home, and go back to the search game screen, it's loading and stay loading whatever I do.

Comment: I mean, maybe can't find anything

Comment: I mean, maybe the board game can't be found

Comment: Oh yes, It can be. Before I try this statenotifier method, 
I managed to recover the data but my problem was to refresh the part of the widget concerned.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're talking about

Comment: Are you asking?

Comment: I'm not asking. I'm sure my request to the remote API is correct

Comment: What are you searching for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248650/discussion-between-collembole-and-my-car).